# how to load components dynamically based on router

Tags: angular, angular-template, angular-router

```
<router-outlet (activate)="onRefresh($event)"></router-outlet>
```

I don't want to load our entire app while accessing the URL (my app size is big now). I want to load the component dynamically according to the route (fetching the new template from the server based on the route). Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: You need to use lazy loading module.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a routing module so that you can define specific components to load upon the router. You can get a clear idea from [here; the docs from angular.](https://angular.io/guide/router)